# How to view available postgres users, without having a user to log in?

Tags: postgresql, nixos

I am using postgres, facing the error:

```
$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist
```

I get a similar error when attempting to connect using my username, and do not know what user I can use to connect. Running `$ psql -l`, attempting to list users, also fails with the same error since I do not have a user to connect and run the command.

**Is there any way to view the available users, when I don't know of a user name that can connect to run `$ psql -l`?**

Is there perhaps a default role that I can use to create my 'postgres' and username roles? Or could I maybe use sudo to look into `/var/db/postgresql` (my postgres data directory) for the postgres user names?

I am running NixOS 17.03.

Comment: How did you install postgres? It gives you an admin username and pass at setup

Comment: @cricket_007 I installed postgres by running '$ nix-env -i postgresql'. Just now I tried uninstalling (with '$ nix-env --uninstall postgresql') and reinstalling by that method and somehow it did not prompt an admin username/password.

Comment: If you're really stuck you can start postgres in single-user mode (see the manual) and run `select * from pg_authid`

Comment: Check [Single-User Mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER)

Comment: Well, it depends on your OS and how it's distributed to the package manager, but often setups up a role of the current user account and a blank password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestions of the comments I shut down my postgres server and restarted in single user mode to run `select * from pg_authid;`, and got the following:

```
$ sudo -u postgres postgres --single -D /var/db/postgresql/
[sudo] password for matthew:

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.11
backend> select * from pg_authid;
         1: rolname     (typeid = 19, len = 64, typmod = -1, byval = f)
         2: rolsuper    (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         3: rolinherit  (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         4: rolcreaterole       (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         5: rolcreatedb (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         6: rolcatupdate        (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         7: rolcanlogin (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         8: rolreplication      (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         9: rolconnlimit        (typeid = 23, len = 4, typmod = -1, byval = t)
        10: rolpassword (typeid = 25, len = -1, typmod = -1, byval = f)
        11: rolvaliduntil       (typeid = 1184, len = 8, typmod = -1, byval = t)
        ----
         1: rolname = "root"    (typeid = 19, len = 64, typmod = -1, byval = f)
         2: rolsuper = "t"      (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         3: rolinherit = "t"    (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         4: rolcreaterole = "t" (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         5: rolcreatedb = "t"   (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         6: rolcatupdate = "t"  (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         7: rolcanlogin = "t"   (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         8: rolreplication = "t"        (typeid = 16, len = 1, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         9: rolconnlimit = "-1" (typeid = 23, len = 4, typmod = -1, byval = t)
        ----
backend>
```

This confirms that there is no 'postgres' role, and shows that there is a 'root' role.